# Flutter Firebase Messaging: Messages not displayed on Android

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, push-notification

I'm working on a Flutter App with Firebase Messaging. The notifications work perfectly fine on iOS. On Android, they work when the app is in the foreground, but are not displayed when the app is in background or terminated. I could already rule out doze mode, as the app has been put to background just seconds before triggering the message. The logfile also says, the message is received by the devices, but somehow not displayed.

The problem also only exists when the app is installed via .apk and not when I build directly with Android Studio, so I thought maybe the fingerprinting could cause the problem. But the messages are received by the device and just not displayed -> so that's not it either, right?

I use firebase_messaging: ^12.0.0 as the plugin.

Here is the implementation of my background handler:

```
static Future<void> setUp() async {
await Firebase.initializeApp(
name: 'Firebase-App',
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
//... iOS stuff
//Enable Foreground-Messages for Android
const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'high_importance_channel', // id
  'High Importance Notifications', // title
  description:
      'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
  importance: Importance.max,
);

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

await configLocalNotification(flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin);

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
    .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
        AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
    ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  //Display Foreground-Message on Android
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    message.hashCode,
    Uri.decodeComponent(message.data['title']).replaceAll('+', ' '),
    Uri.decodeComponent(message.data['message']).replaceAll('+', ' '),
    NotificationDetails(
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
        channel.id,
        channel.name,
        channelDescription: channel.description,
        icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
        importance: Importance.max,
      ),
    ),
    payload: json.encode(message.data),
  );
});

await FirebaseMessaging.instance
    .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
        alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);

FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
}

static Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(
  RemoteMessage message) async {
await Firebase.initializeApp();

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'high_importance_channel', // id
  'High Importance Notifications', // title
  description:
      'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
  importance: Importance.max,
);

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
  message.hashCode,
  Uri.decodeComponent(message.data['title']).replaceAll('+', ' '),
  Uri.decodeComponent(message.data['message']).replaceAll('+', ' '),
  NotificationDetails(
    android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
      channel.id,
      channel.name,
      channelDescription: channel.description,
      icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
      importance: Importance.max,
      // other properties...
    ),
  ),
  payload: json.encode(message.data),
);
}

static Future<void> configLocalNotification(
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin) async {
const initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
const initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
const initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
    iOS: initializationSettingsIOS, android: initializationSettingsAndroid);

//Handle on click event when App is in foreground or background
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
    onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);

//handle on click event when app is terminated
final NotificationAppLaunchDetails? notificationAppLaunchDetails =
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();

if (notificationAppLaunchDetails?.didNotificationLaunchApp ?? false) {
  final String? selectedNotificationPayload =
      notificationAppLaunchDetails!.payload;
  debugPrint(
      'notification payload on launch: $selectedNotificationPayload');

  await onSelectNotification(selectedNotificationPayload);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help, I'm really at the end of the line here!

Comment: add your implementation of background services for this.

Comment: I added it, just let me know if you need more info